# Insert a record with an apostrophe mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert a record with an apostrophe into a MySQL database using PHP. Following is my code:

```
$importer_name =mysql_escape_string ($objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1,3)->getValue());
$exporter_name = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, 3)->getValue();
$prod_quantity_unit = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1,6)->getValue();
$prod_fob_value = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(5,6)->getValue();
$prod_quantity = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1,8)->getValue();
$prod_fob_unit= $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(5,8)->getValue();
$prod_gross_waight= $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1,10)->getValue();
$prod_cif_value= $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(5,10)->getValue();
$prod_net_weight= $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1,12)->getValue();
$prod_cif_unit_price= $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(5,12)->getValue();
$prod_brand= $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(5,14)->getValue();
$hs_code = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1,17)->getValue();
$shipping_date = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(5,17)->getValue();
$customs = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1,19)->getValue();
$transport_company = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(5,19)->getValue();
$country_of_origin = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1,21)->getValue();
$transport_mode = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(5,21)->getValue();
$country_of_trade = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1,23)->getValue(); 
$hs_code_description = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1,26)->getValue();
$product_description = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1,28)->getValue();

$insertquery="INSERT INTO tb_peru_data
    (importer_name,exporter_name,product_quantity_unit,
    product_fob_unit,product_quantity,product_fob_value,
   product_gross_weight,product_cif_value,
   product_net_weight,product_cif_unit_price,
   product_brand,shipping_hs_code,shipping_date,
   shipping_customs,shipping_transport_company,
   shipping_country_of_origin,shipping_transport_mode,
   shipping_country_of_trade,hs_code_description,
   product_description) 
    VALUES
('$importer_name','$exporter_name','$prod_quantity_unit',
   '$prod_fob_unit','$prod_quantity','$prod_fob_value',
   '$prod_gross_waight','$prod_cif_value','$prod_net_weight',
   '$prod_cif_unit_price','$prod_brand','$hs_code','$shipping_date',
   '$customs','$transport_company','$country_of_origin',
   '$transport_mode','$country_of_trade',
   '$hs_code_description','$product_description')";

      mysql_query($insertquery)or die('ErrorrPERU: '.mysql_error());
     /*$del="DELETE * FROM tb_excel_file";
     mysql_query($del);*/
```

?>

This does not work, and gives the following error:

> you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
>   to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
>   `'s','12U','6','9','54',
>   '34.83','55.5','31.83','6.17','','7323931000','2008/04/1'` at line 3

Comment: Just to be sure, you *are* using the `$importer_name` variable in your query, right? Can you please show the line of code that actually runs the query? -- Also, inb4 "mysql_* is deprecated" schtick.

Comment: Show your query please.. looks more like you insert more columns instead of rows

Comment: Am I the only one having difficulties in seeing which is the apostrophe that might cause the problem? Can you show us the tale structure and the query?

Comment: $insertquery="INSERT INTO tb_peru_data(importer_name) VALUES
 ('$importer_name')";


 
mysql_query($insertquery)or die('ErrorrPERU: '.mysql_error());

Comment: So you're escaping `$importer_name`: what about all the other string values (e.g. `$exporter_name`)

Comment: oh please just use PDO http://us2.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Comment: Actually 's use only importer_name so i am facing problem in $importer_name

Comment: `$importer _name` and `$exporter_name` come from the same cell in the Excel file, so they are the same value... if one needs escaping, then the other does as well.... as do all the other string values you're reading from cells

Comment: To avoid the need to escape your values, you need to switch from the MySQL extension to MySQLi or PDO, and start using prepared statements with bind variables

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysqli_real_escape_string` instead of deprecated `mysql_real_escape_string`
This function will force you to input mysql table / database.
This way your collation will be considered while escaping

Comment: If OP is using the MySQL extension, then using MySQLi isn't particularly going to help unless they switch all their database usage to MySQLi.... in which case, they should use prepared statements/bind variables

Comment: What are you adding precisely, show us more data/code please.

Comment: $importer_name =$objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1,3)->getValue(); $imp_name=implode(" ' ",$importer_name);

Answer (score -1):

You can use [real_escape_string()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) in PHP. You need to escape the apostrophe (that is, tell SQL that the apostrophe is to be taken literally and not as the beginning or end of a string). To add more, I'd say that you can also use PDO, but consider using addslashes($string) and stripslashes($string).

Comment: How does `implode()` help with writing to a DB?

Comment: I made the changes BenM. I misunderstood the question initially.

Comment: No worries. Feel free to edit my answer should anything needs to be improved.

Comment: $importer_name =$objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1,3)->getValue();
 $imp_name=implode(" ' ",$importer_name);

Comment: Don't use implode, remove that.